# ROUND function in CASE WHEN is not working

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I have the following query, I left some things out and changed names for the question:

```
WITH GET_T AS (
Select table.key
       ,COUNT(DISTINCT(T1.ID)) OVER (PARTITION BY(T.KEY)) as Count  
FROM T
     Left Join T1 ON T1.key = T.key
)
  
SELECT T5.key,
       case when Count > 0 then ROUND(SUM(total_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY(T4.key))/ Count, 3)
           else 0
             end AS total_invoiced_amount
FROM T3
LEFT JOIN T4 ON T4.key = T3.key
LEFT JOIN T5 on T3.id = T4.d
```

In my result set, the TOTAL_INVOICED_AMOUNT column is not rounded to three decimal places. What do I change here so I have the 3 decimal places at all times

- 0.000, 80.000, 175.160

Currently I am getting

- 105.5 when it should be 105.500
- 80 when it should be 80.000
- 0 when it should be 0.000

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: Added current results.

Comment: So it's rounding correctly, you just expect to see the trailing 0's ?

Comment: Yes, thats right

Comment: Oracle does not use trailing zeros for numbers, you have to convert it to a char

Answer (score 3):

To display trailing zeroes, you must convert the value to text:

```
to_char(case when Count > 0 then ROUND(SUM(total_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY(T4.key))/ Count, 3)
       else 0
         end,'FM999,9999,990.000')
```